# Add APN (+ Button) Option Missing

Tags: apn, android-one

So my gf and I both have the Xiaomi Mi A2, her works perfectly, but when I tried to setup mine, I realized I had no data connection.

In order to make it work with my provider, I must configure a new custom APN but for some reason, the button to add a new one is missing. I´ve checked, however, my gf's mobile, despite being apparently the same in every aspect, she has such button.

Then I thought there must be some differences between both devices operating system's version, so I wonder if is there a way to compare both to check what I'm missing in order to have the option that I need?

If not, any way to fix this would be really appreciated. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: What provider? In some cases the carrier locks APN changes with the SIM card, but you can't remove the SIM and set them up either as the SIM over rides any manual change. What I am saying is that this is likely not a device issues, but a carrier/SIM issue.

Comment: @acejavelin thanks for the reply. As I mentioned, I've 2 identical phones, and in one of them I can configure the apn, whilst in the other (the one I have to use), I can't. It´s clearly a device issue.

Comment: Dial `*#*#4636#*#*` from your phone app, you will get a menu where first item is phone info. Tap the 3 dots menu on top right which has "enable data". Try that or by toggling carrier info in the menu and see if it helps. Factory reset is always an option but ideally if nothing else works

Comment: Dane, is there a reason why you reverted the changes I earlier introduced in your question? I definitely improved it, except the beginning where I erred on replacing the word GF. Your title does not tell us what you want with the question. I ensured that a person understands what the asker wants just by reading the title alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, without the SIM card or other cards the plus button to add APN appears, which doesnt when having my own card.

Finally I found an app called [MyApp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.mpao.myapn&hl=es), that after installing, it allowed me to edit the APNs, so now everything works as it should, despite it's a workaround.